# Proper margins in custom enumeration/itemize environements

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem, nesting

I am using two custom list environments (`itemize-compact` and `descriptionhang`), which work fine on their own, but not when I nest them.

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=27.5mm,right=27.5mm,bottom=27.5mm,top=27.5mm}

%Line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.115}

%Paragraph indentation & spacing
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.75ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

%Itemize with less spacing
\newenvironment{itemize-compact}
{\vspace{-1.5ex plus 0.2ex}
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{-1.5ex plus 0.2ex}}
{\end{itemize}}

%Description environment with newlines and bit of spacing after the item titles
\newenvironment{descriptionhang}{%
  \begin{description}[labelsep=0pt]%
    \LetLtxMacro{\olditem}{\item}%
    \renewcommandx\item[2][1,2]{\olditem\ifthenelse{\isempty{##1}}{}{\hspace{13.5pt}\textbf{##1}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{##2}}{}{\ ##2}\hfill\\[3pt plus 0.75pt minus 1.75pt]}}%
  {\end{description}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Itemize-compact non-nested:
\begin{itemize-compact}
\item Blah
\item Bleh
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize-compact}

Itemize-compact nested in a descriptionhang:
\begin{descriptionhang}
\item[Hello world]
\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize-compact}
\item Blah
\item Bleh
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize-compact}

\item[Foobar]
\lipsum[2]
\end{descriptionhang}

\end{document}
```

This produces:[image: MWE result]

Notice that the `itemize-compact` environment which is nested in the `descriptionhang` produces an incorrect result. The bullets are in the right spot but the text is not.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\item` macro renewed within `descriptionhang` is inherited in the nested `itemize-compact` environment. The same goes for the `labelsep` specification. Here's a modification to your MWE that keeps the same format when nested:

[image: Nested environments itemize-compact/descriptionhang]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=27.5mm,right=27.5mm,bottom=27.5mm,top=27.5mm}

%Line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.115}
\LetLtxMacro{\itcompitem}{\item}% <------- Store copy of \item
%Paragraph indentation & spacing
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.75ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

%Itemize with less spacing
\newenvironment{itemize-compact}
{\vspace{-1.5ex plus 0.2ex}
\LetLtxMacro{\item}{\itcompitem}% <------- Restore copy of \item
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=1ex]% <------- Fixed labelsep
  \setlength{\itemsep}{-1.5ex plus 0.2ex}}
{\end{itemize}}

%Description environment with newlines and bit of spacing after the item titles
\newenvironment{descriptionhang}{%
  \begin{description}[labelsep=0pt]%
    \LetLtxMacro{\olditem}{\item}%
    \renewcommandx\item[2][1,2]{\olditem\ifthenelse{\isempty{##1}}{}{\hspace{13.5pt}\textbf{##1}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{##2}}{}{\ ##2}\hfill\\[3pt plus 0.75pt minus 1.75pt]}}%
  {\end{description}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Itemize-compact non-nested:
\begin{itemize-compact}
\item Blah
\item Bleh
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize-compact}

Itemize-compact nested in a descriptionhang:
\begin{descriptionhang}
\item[Hello world]
\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize-compact}
\item Blah
\item Bleh
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize-compact}

\item[Foobar]
\lipsum[2]
\end{descriptionhang}

\end{document}​
```

`\item` is stored *outside* any of the environments to obtain a "clean" version. Also, `itemize-compact` is set with a fixed `labelsep` of `1ex`, allowing a constant separation even when it is nested.